# How to print a single column from a jagged char array

Tags: java

so I've been trying to create a program which allows the user to select what row and column they want from a square containing various words. Right now the code will ask for the user to input a row, if they type in 2 it will print out 'LAVA' as that is the second row in the square. Problem is I can't figure out how to create a method which can print out a column, so if the user typed 1 they would get 'PLOT' as that is word contained in the first column. My code is currently as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MagicSquare {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[][] magicSquare = {
            {,},
            {'P', 'R', 'E', 'Y'},
            {'L', 'A', 'V', 'A'},
            {'O', 'V', 'E', 'R'},
            {'T', 'E', 'N', 'D'},
       };

    displayRow(magicSquare);
    displayCol(magicSquare);
}

static void displayRow(char[][] rowIn)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row;
    System.out.println("What row do you want to display (1-4): ");
    row = input.nextInt();
    while(row<1 || row>4)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid row number!!");
        System.out.println("Enter again (1-4 only): ");
        row = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 4; i <= rowIn[1].length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(rowIn[row]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

static void displayCol(char[][] colIn)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int col;
    System.out.println("What column do you want to display (1-4): ");
    col = input.nextInt();
    while(col<1 || col>4)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid col number!!");
        System.out.println("Enter again (1-4 only): ");
        col = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 4; i <= colIn[1].length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(colIn[col]);

    }
}
}
```

The displayCol doesn't work as it does the exact same thing that displayRow does but I cannot figure out how to get it to print a column instead of a row. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How would you do it if you weren't a computer? Which array would you need to print the chosen column from? You have two arrays: the rows are easy, because all the row's values are in the same array. Columns have their content spread across multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop should be over a particular column with a varying row. Something like,

```
for (int i = 1; i < colIn.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(colIn[i][col - 1]);
}
System.out.println();
```

I tested it with your specified input, I get

```
PLOT
```